# Who, between the player and the DM, decides the actions of an independent mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat

Let's say a player buys an Elephant or a Warhorse for his character's mount, and wants to sometimes let said mount act independently so that it can attack enemies and possibly make them prone.

My question is : considering that the mount acts by itself, but is still owned by the player's character, who controls its movement and actions between the player and the DM ?

My guess would be the DM, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @xdaizu don't answer in comments. Elaborate on your comment and post as an answer.

Comment: @DevSolar Answer only in answer posts, please.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## The DM Controls

If you are not actively giving orders, then the mount is basically a NPC not under your control and therefore the DM determines it's actions.

If you are actively giving orders, then the mount will follow them.

You can't choose to NOT give orders AND still control the mount. It needs to be one or the other, or there is no reason to differentiate.

Comment: This answer mixes *player* control and *character* control. It might still be the right result, but not for the stated reason.

Comment: @fectin I'm not sure that in this case there is a difference. Whether the You is the PC or the player, the idea of controlling mounts doesn't really change.

Comment: Well... if the PC is unconscious, the player can’t possibly control the mount.

Answer (score 28):

By the rules, the DM controls.

***But,*** in every case I've ever seen this happen at the table, the DM has enough going on that they just delegate this to the player. This usually comes with the understanding that the player will keep the creature's actions reasonable for its intelligence and training, and not hog table time from other players.

That's either discussed up front, or comes up when the player:

- tells the DM "hey, my horse is your NPC now" in the midst of an ambush by six lizardfolk and a t-rex just as the party's raft reaches the rapids, or
- says "my elephant sneaks forward into the dark cave, picks the locks on the dungeon doors, and reports back".

There is also often an implicit understanding with familiars, mounts, and other "pets" — if you keep it out of the combat, enemies won't target it. It may even get skipped over in taking damage from area attacks. But if the creature is making independent attacks, it's fair game. This isn't in the rules *at all*, but again from experience is common practice. (Just as getting splashed with acid doesn't destroy your bard's fancy noble outfit.)

I'd suggest a conversation with the DM about this — or with the player, if you're the DM.

Answer (score 1):

A mix of the two, player and DM direction, works just fine.  My approach is to let the player decide, as long as he stays within what the mount is capable of, and is trained to do.  The more the player has invested in training, the more the player can use that to direct the mount in a balanced and realistic manner.  If the player abuses the privilege of deciding, by having the mount act unreasonably, then I'll offer him nudges, or take over directing it.